# tabhost in Android example force closing in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

I wrote a simple tabhost example which is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

this is in main.xml
so i set the setcontentview to main.xml

```
public class AndroidtabhostActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

It works fine in the android 4.0 emulator but when i run it on android 2.1 emulator it force closes with these logs in ddms

```
03-16 17:19:08.295: E/AndroidRuntime(1579):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
03-16 17:39:27.016: E/AndroidRuntime(2092): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{banana.com/banana.com.AndroidtabhostActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at banana.com.AndroidtabhostActivity.onCreate(AndroidtabhostActivity.java:11)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-16 17:39:27.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2092):     ... 11 more
```

Why is it so ???Can somebody please explain

After changing as samir said I am still getting an exception

```
03-16 17:50:03.925: E/AndroidRuntime(2372): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-16 17:50:03.936: E/AndroidRuntime(2372):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: extends TabActivity and if error occur then post full logcat

Comment: it still gives exception .I updated the question with the log after extending tabactivity instead of activity. still the problem persists

Comment: You could try the official [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) too and see if there are some differences.

Comment: @toto2 yup I am checking that in the meantime....however this is odd .. to run in one emulator and not in another that's quite something more than what i can handle at my level of expertise..however i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup atleast one tab otherwise it gives an error in 2.1 while 4.0 handles it without that so I added this code after setcontentview

```
TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.mytabhost);
    th.setup();
    TabSpec ts = th.newTabSpec("whatevver");
    ts.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    ts.setIndicator("TAB1");
    th.addTab(ts);
```

and it ran fine in both the emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Android's Tabhost is buggy. Please check my [blog](http://pavandroid.blogspot.in/2010/07/customizing-buttons-we-can-customize_1669.html) for more info to create Tabs

Search for tabhost to get the corresponding information immediately.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.